# Rails accepts nested attributes many to many N+1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models: User, UserTask, and Task

The UserTask model has an attribute can_perform:boolean.

The Task model has an attribute description:string

I want to build a nested form so a user can update the join table UserTask's can_perform attribute.

In my User model I have the following:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_tasks
```

In the view I have something like the following:

= f.simple_fields_for :user_tasks do |user_task_form|

```
    %tr
      %td
        = user_task_form.object.can_perform
      %td.td-right
        = user_task_form.input :can_perform, label: false
```

The problem I have is accessing a UserTask's Task record.

If I try user_task_form.object.task this results in an N+1 message from: https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet

Is there a way to include the Task model for each of the UserTasks?

I want to display the task description with the can perform checkbox.

Comment: Do you still get an N+1 message if you use `@user = User.find(id).includes(:user_tasks => :tasks)` in the controller?

Comment: The only difference: User.where(current_user.id).includes(:user_tasks => :task).first